# Get data from database and display to blade template in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when I learning laravel. My views include `master.blade.php` and `top.blade.php` file. 
In `master.blade.php`, I used `@include('top')` command to get content show UI. But now I don't know how to get and passing database to `top.blade.php`. I was  used direct `App\Article;` to do this. can anyone help me? thanks.

Master.blade.php file

```
@include('top')
```

Top.blade.php file

```
<?php 
use App\Article;
$articles = Article::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(1)->get();
 ?>
@foreach ($articles as $a)
{{ $a->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: More answers here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54860667/3057779 You can also call controller function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<?php 
$articles = \App\Article::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(1)->get();
?>
```

But it's better to keep data logic in a model or a controller and pass it to the views.

Comment: Thanks @Mezenin. if my top.blade.php  appearing in all pages, then what do I do?

Comment: @Dung, this should work in all views which include `top.blade.php`

Comment: Is there a better way to handle laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Juste use a Controller to pass database data in to your view, it should be

ArticlesController.php

```
$articles = Article::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(1)->get();
return view('master', compact('articles');
```

It's just an example, but now top.blade.php which is included in master, will contain $articles.

Comment: Thanks @Dumas. follow you, I must to call view top.blade.php in all controller to show top.blade.php in all page.