# Laravel 5.5 call Controller function from blade view with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a slider of products and i'm trying to find the lowest price of each product.

So i'm trying, first of all, to successfully call a function from a Controller and pass the `id` of the product and also print it out.

*blade.php*

```
 <span class="text-bold">
   @php
    use App\Http\Controllers\ServiceProvider;
    echo ServiceProvider::getLowestPrice($product_cat->id);
   @endphp
 </span>
```

*Route*

```
Route::post('/getLowestPrice/{id}', 'ServiceProvider@getLowestPrice');
```

*Controller*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ServiceProvider extends Controller
{
    public static function getLowestPrice($id) {
        return $id;
    }
}
```

And I get an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
```

Any idea why `use` is not working here?

Comment: you can't use `use` keyword inside method

Comment: @Ali its seems that i can't yes. But is there any way to get the actual return of the function ?

Comment: Template is for __rendering__ data. Prepare your data in a controller, not in a template.

Comment: @EmilePels I know, but the data of the slider is not always the same. They keep changing so i will prefer the bad practice :(

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios You should get the data in your controller (or service) and then pass it to the view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can't use `use` keyword inside method

you can write the full class path , like this

```
 <span class="text-bold">
   @php
    echo App\Http\Controllers\ServiceProvider::getLowestPrice($product_cat->id);
   @endphp
 </span>
```

Comment: You can create an Alias to your class in the file config/app.php

'aliases' => [
  'ServiceProvider' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ServiceProvider',
]

After that blade will recognize the ServiceProvider class

Answer (score 30):

@Ali is obviously correct, and I suggest you accept his answer.

I'd like to add, though, that there's a service injection directive as well which was built for this exact purpose, and which is a little cleaner to use.

```
@inject('provider', 'App\Http\Controllers\ServiceProvider')

<span class="text-bold">
    {{ $provider::getLowestPrice($product_cat->id) }}
</span>
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#service-injection

Comment: Joel humbly said accept @Ali's answer but I think this answer is better as it shows the "right" way to do the equivalent of `use` in Laravel

Comment: Thanks, Joel, this works on Laravel 8 as well, the prerequisite of this is to define a static function in the controller.

Comment: How can i call non static method?

Answer (score 3):

```
//Create a static type function in your controller.The function must be a static type function.

    <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class ServiceProvider extends Controller
    { 
        public static function getLowestPrice($val){
            // do your stuff or return something.
        }
    }

    //Then Call the ServiceProvider Controller function from view


    //include the controller class.
    <?php use App\Http\Controllers\ServiceProvider;?>
    //call the controller function in php way with passing args.
    <?php echo ServiceProvider::getLowestPrice($product_cat->id); ?>
    // Or call the controller function in blade way.
    {{ServiceProvider::getLowestPrice($product_cat->id)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be even easier, you can call it directly like this:

```
<span class="text-bold">
    {{App\ServiceProvider::getLowestPrice($product_cat->id)}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple concept, to call controller function from view is:
e.g. You have a Button in view with href="Your URL"

```
 <a href="/user/projects/{id}" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
```

Now define a route in web.php:

```
Route::get('/user/projects/{id}', 'user_controller@showProject');
```

A function in respective controller will be looks like this:

```
 public function showProject($id){
 $post =posts::find($id);
 return view('user.show_projects')->with('post', $post);;
    }
```

I hope this will help you.