# How to call function in controller from blade template

Tags: laravel, radio-button

I am trying to call a controller function from blade file (as well as passing some variables) from an onlick function of a radio button. However, I can't seem to call the function from controller in blade file yet (nothing happened when clicking the choice)

**My blade file**

```
<div class="container box">
      @foreach($questionList as $post)
      <div class = "test">
        <p>
          <strong>{{$post->getQuestionId()}}.  {{$post->getQuestion()}}</strong>
          <br>
        </p>
        <span>
           <input type="radio" name="{{$post->getQuestionId()}}" href="{{action('questionController@updateChoice',$data->$post->getQuestionId())}}" value="a">
           <label for="a">{{$post->getChoiceA()}}</label>
        </span>
        <span>
           <input type="radio" name="{{$post->getQuestionId()}}" value="b"> <label for="b">{{$post->getChoiceB()}}</label></span>
        <span>
          <input type="radio" name="{{$post->getQuestionId()}}" value="c"> 
          <label for="c">{{$post->getChoiceC()}}</label>
         </span>
        <span>
          <input type="radio" name="{{$post->getQuestionId()}}" value="d"> 
          <label for="d">{{$post->getChoiceD()}}</label>
        </span>
        <br>
      </div>
      @endforeach
  </div>
```

**My questionController method**

```
   function updateChoice($id)
    {
     /// do function in here
    }
```

Do I need to do anything else ?

Comment: `<input>` elements don't have a `href` value. Use `onclick`/AJAX. (Also, a `<label>`'s `for` attribute should point to an `id` attribute of another element, you don't have `id`s set)

Comment: Thank you for correct. However, when I try _onlick_ , it has error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input . Do you know the correct way to call ?

Comment: This is a great example of where Laravel Livewire will help you

Comment: can you read this link or try it please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474160/laravel-5-5-call-controller-function-from-blade-view-with-parameter/48474187

Comment: @vandanrigel I tried service injection, however the function got immediately called when I load the page.